# Проблема прыжка зума карты на -1 при поиске через SearchControl

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Наблюдаю следующую проблему: 
при использовании SearchControl каждый поисковый запрос уменьшает zoom карты на -1.

Добавление setZoom в then не помогает, карта всё равно с каждым запросом отдаляется.

Эту проблему можно наблюдать в песочнице, если несколько раз что-либо поискать через форму поиска:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo

Подскажите, как решить?

Comment: Какую задачу вы хотите решить? Почему поведение кажется вам некорректным?

Comment: Мне нужно устранить поведение с зумом и делать только поиск.Если я сделаю десяток запросов, то увижу всю карту мира с материками, как-то это неправильно. Нормально: оставаться на прежнем зуме, не перемещая карту.

Comment: Какую задачу вы хотите решить в результате? Какую карту хотите получить?
Вы говорите, что так ненормально, но непонятно, в каком кейсе человек ищет на одном зуме одно и тоже 10 раз подряд.

Comment: Необязательно искать одно и тоже, достаточно просто что-либо искать. Мне нужно чтобы пользователь мог посмотреть аптеки, магазины, школы и сады рядом со своим домом. Через несколько запросов карта улетает в космос, что вынуждает зумить карту обратно. Мне нужно, чтобы поиск по карте происходил без перемещения в пространстве от изначальной точки просмотра.

Comment: Вы делаете что-то вроде панели инфраструктуры? Такого плана http://жк-дом-на-блюхера-спб.рф/ ?

Comment: Да, что-то вроде этого

Comment: Это нужно делать запросами в HTTP API Геопоиска, использовать для этого поисковый контрол и переопределять отображение результатов запрещено условиями использования